# Having trouble with C pointers

Tags: c

First of all, im a begginer C programmer, studying in a university. I need to do a program that is kinda like a data base. Thus far i have made the function to input new data, it works, but compiler shows a few warning and notes, i tried a lot of things, but nothing helped. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct subjects{
    char *subjName[100];
    char *lectName[100];
    char *lectSurname[100];
    double credits;
    double studentnum;
}subj;

char subjectname[][100];
char lecturername[][100];
char lecturersurname[][100];
int credits[100];
int students[100];
int newentry=0;

void listInput();
void listEdit();
void listDelete();
void listPrint();
int userChoice();

int main() {
    int select;
    int r=1;
    while(r!=0){
        select=userChoice();
    switch(select){
        case 1:
        listPrint();
        break;

        case 2:
        listInput();
        break;

        case 3:
        listDelete();
        break;

        case 4:
        listEdit();
        break;

        case 0:
        r=0;
        break;
      }
    }
    return 0;
}

int userChoice(){
    int choice,input=0,check;
    printf("(1). View all the data\n");
    printf("(2). Enter new data\n");
    printf("(3). Delete data\n");
    printf("(4). Edit data\n");
    printf("(0). Exit\n");
    printf("-----------------------------\n");

    while(input!=1){
        printf("Enter your choice\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if(choice>4 || choice<0){
            printf("Invalid input \n");
        }
        else
            input = 1;

    }
    return choice;
}

void listPrint(){
    for(int i=0; i<newentry; i++){
        printf("%d, %s, %s, %s, %d, %d\n",i+1, subjectname[i], lecturername[i], lecturersurname[i], credits[i], students[i]);
    }
}

void listInput(){
    int i;
    char firstLetter,term;
    printf("Enter the name of the subject \n");
    while(scanf("%s", &subj.subjName)!=1)
        printf("Error, subject name must be a text ");
    printf("Enter the name of the lecturer \n");
    int valid=0;
    while(valid!=1){
        while(scanf("%s", &subj.lectName)!=1)
            printf("Error, lecturer's' name must be a text ");
        firstLetter=*subj.lectName;     
            if(firstLetter>65 && firstLetter<90 && isalpha(firstLetter)){
                valid=1;
            }
            else
                printf("Error, lecturer's name must start with a capital letter, try again \nEnter the name of the lecturer \n");
    }
    valid=0;
    printf("Enter the surname of the lecturer\n");
    while(valid!=1){
        while(scanf("%s", &subj.lectSurname)!=1)
            printf("Error, lecturer's surname must be a text ");
        firstLetter=*subj.lectSurname;
        if(firstLetter>65 && firstLetter<90 && isalpha(firstLetter)){
            valid=1;
            }
        else
            printf("Lecturer's surname must start with a capital letter, try again \nEnter the surname of the lecturer \n");
    }
    printf("Enter the amount of credits in course \n");
    while(1){
        scanf("%lf", &subj.credits);
        if(subj.credits<0 || subj.credits != (int)subj.credits)
            printf("Error, amount of credits must be a positive integer, try again \n");
        if(subj.credits>0 && subj.credits == (int)subj.credits)
            break;
    }
    printf("Enter the number of students \n");
    while(1){
        scanf("%lf", &subj.studentnum);
        if(subj.studentnum<0 || subj.studentnum != (int)subj.studentnum)
            printf("Error, number of students must be a positive integer,try again \n");
        if(subj.studentnum>0 && subj.studentnum == (int)subj.studentnum)
            break;
    }
    printf("Added a new entry.\n\n");
    strncpy(subjectname[newentry], subj.subjName, 99);
    strncpy(lecturername[newentry], subj.lectName, 99);
    strncpy(lecturersurname[newentry], subj.lectSurname, 99);
    credits[newentry]=subj.credits;
    students[newentry]=subj.studentnum;
    newentry++;
}

void listDelete(){
    printf("33333333333");
}

void listEdit(){
    printf("4444444");
}
```

And the warnings:

```
In function 'listInput':
96  14  [Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
108 14  [Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
132 33  [Warning] passing argument 2 of 'strncpy' from incompatible pointer type
79  9   [Note] expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type 'char **'
133 34  [Warning] passing argument 2 of 'strncpy' from incompatible pointer type
79  9   [Note] expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type 'char **'
134 37  [Warning] passing argument 2 of 'strncpy' from incompatible pointer type
79  9   [Note] expected 'const char * restrict' but argument is of type 'char **
At top level:
14  6   [Warning] array 'subjectname' assumed to have one element
15  6   [Warning] array 'lecturername' assumed to have one element
16  6   [Warning] array 'lecturersurname' assumed to have one element
```

What can i do to fix those warnings? The program works just fine, but i cant pass if i dont fix the warnings.

Comment: Have you googled the warning messages?

Comment: Where you have `char *subjName[100]`, etc., you probably want just `char subjName[100]`. The former is an array of 100 *pointers* to characters, while the latter is an array of characters, which is what C programs generally use to simulate "strings".

Comment: For example, your first warning is because `subj.lectName` is an array of pointers, which makes `subj.lectName` a pointer to pointers. So when you only do one  dereference, `*subj.lectName`, that result is still a pointer and you're assigning that to a character. What  is this statement supposed to be doing? Examine your data types carefully. In this case, the warning is actually pointing out a programming error. C just doesn't make the assumption whether you intended that mismatch or not, so only flags it as a warning.

Comment: Note that your three static arrays `char subjectname[][100];` etc have a size of 0 (MSVC). Your last three warnings relate to this. You can only omit the first dimension when this is used as a function parameter, for example `int fun(char subjectname[][100])`

Comment: @WeatherVane you're mistaken though, see [C11 6.9.2p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.2p5). `char subjectname[][100];` without an initializer is a *tentative definition* that, unless a definition with an initializer is present, means exactly the same as  `char subjectname[1][100];`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala was is unexpected that the infamous MSVC would report a size of 0? When I added the line `subjectname[0][0] = '*';` to my size test program I got *test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _subjectname referenced in function _main*. It only compiled cleanly with `char subjectname[1][100];` OP's program does not go further from the tentative definition.

Comment: well, MSVC might not be a C compiler.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala so, does say gcc allow `subjectname[0][0] = '*';` after only the tentative definition `char subjectname[][100];`?

Comment: @WeatherVane of course it does. Because a tentative definition becomes a definition. But **g++** does *not* because it is not valid C++.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala but my first comment was still good, because OP uses `subjectname[newentry]`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapalauh ... but `for(int i=0; i<newentry; i++)` won't iterate, because `newentry` remains as `0`. So why did the compiler emit those 3 warnings? Didn't realise that `newentry` would be `0`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a better way to do things

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    typedef struct{
        char *subjName;
        char *lectName;
        char *lectSurname;
        double credits;
        double num_students;
    }Subject;

    typedef struct{
        Subject **subjs;
        int num_subjs;
    }Subjects;

    void listInput();
    void listEdit();
    void listDelete();
    void listPrint();
    int userChoice();

    int main() {
    Subjects *subjects = malloc(sizeof(Subjects));
    subjects->num_subjs = 0;
    subjects->subjs = NULL;

    int r=1;
    while(r!=0){
        int select=userChoice();
        switch(select){
            case 1:
            listPrint(subjects);
            break;

            case 2:
            listInput(&subjects);
            break;

            case 3:
            listDelete();
            break;

            case 4:
            listEdit();
            break;

            case 0:
            r=0;
            break;
          }
    }
    return 0;
}

int userChoice(){
    int choice,input=0,check;
    printf("(1). View all the data\n");
    printf("(2). Enter new data\n");
    printf("(3). Delete data\n");
    printf("(4). Edit data\n");
    printf("(0). Exit\n");
    printf("-----------------------------\n");

    while(input!=1){
        printf("Enter your choice\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if(choice>4 || choice<0){
            printf("Invalid input \n");
        }
        else
            input = 1;

    }
    return choice;
}

void listPrint(Subjects *subjects){
    for(int i=0; i< subjects->num_subjs; i++){
        printf("%d, %s, %s, %s, %d, %d\n",i+1, subjects->subjs[i]->subjName, subjects->subjs[i]->lectName, subjects->subjs[i]->lectSurname, subjects->subjs[i]->credits, subjects->subjs[i]->num_students);
    }
}

char *getln()
{
    char *line = NULL, *tmp = NULL;
    size_t size = 0, index = 0;
    int ch = 1;

    while (ch) {
        ch = getc(stdin);

        if (ch == '\n')
            ch = 0;

        if (size <= index) {
            size += 1;
            tmp = realloc(line, size);
            if (!tmp) {
                free(line);
                line = NULL;
                break;
            }
            line = tmp;
        }

        line[index++] = ch;
    }

    return line;
}

int isText(char *str,char *name){
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str);i++){
        if((str[i]<'A' || str[i]>'z') && str[i]!=' '){
            printf("Error, %s must be a text \n",name);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int isNegative(int n){
    if(n < 0){
        printf("Error, number of students must be a positive integer,try again \n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void listInput(Subjects **p_subjects){ 
  while ( getchar() != '\n' );

    Subject *new_subj = malloc(sizeof(Subject));
    new_subj->subjName = NULL;
    new_subj->lectName = NULL;
    new_subj->lectSurname = NULL;
    new_subj->credits = 0;
    new_subj->num_students = 0;

    do{
        printf("Enter the name of the subject \n");
        new_subj->subjName = getln();
    }while(!isText(new_subj->subjName,"Subject name"));

    do{
        printf("Enter the name of the lecturer \n");
        new_subj->lectName = getln();
    }while(!isText(new_subj->lectName,"Lecturer's name"));

    do{

       printf("Enter the surname of the lecturer\n");
       new_subj->lectSurname = getln();
        //Convert to uppercase
        new_subj->lectSurname[0] &= '_';
    }while(!isText(new_subj->lectSurname,"Lecturer's surname"));

    do{
       printf("Enter the number of credits \n");
       scanf("%d", &new_subj->credits);
    }while(isNegative(new_subj->num_students));

    do{
       printf("Enter the number of students \n");
       scanf("%d", &new_subj->num_students);
    }while(isNegative(new_subj->num_students));

    (*p_subjects)->subjs = realloc((*p_subjects)->subjs,sizeof(Subject*)*(++(*p_subjects)->num_subjs));
    (*p_subjects)->subjs[(*p_subjects)->num_subjs-1] = new_subj;
    printf("Added a new entry.\n\n");
}

void listDelete(){
    printf("33333333333");
}

void listEdit(){
    printf("4444444");
}
```

Comment: Damn, thank you for all of your effort. The thing is, i am just a beginner, and i dont really understand more than half of your code, and i need to explain the code to my proffesor in order to pass. Will definately examine your code and try to use parts of it. Also, in structs, i can only save 1 subject, and all the previous data has to go into a static/dynamic array

Comment: Which parts do you not understand? I'd be happy to explain.

Comment: Almost everything tbh, but i will try to examine it myself, or maybe add parts of your code to mine. Also, in structs, i can only save 1 subject, and all the previous data has to go into a static/dynamic array. Anyway, i will try to understand it myself and really really thank you for your effort

Comment: Ok, good luck! Also of the subjects are saved the dynamic array subjects->subj. If you want to get the last one you could get it at subjects->subj[subjects->num_subjs-1].

Comment: I especially dont understand your getln() function

Comment: What that function allows for is to dynamically allocate an inputed string. With scanf you have to have a string with a static size. Ex: char subjName[100]. This function allows you to have char *subjName, so the size is set dynamically depending on the length of the input (it have greater than 100 characters for example). The function essentially reads each character and reallocates the new required amount of space until it encounters a newline. realloc returns null if there was an error allocating space. So if !tmp it deletes the line and quits getting input.

Comment: Also the reason I add 1 to size is because the sizeof(char) is 1 byte in C. (size += sizeof(char) would have been also correct and maybe more obvious)